# Trace Differentiation with Pauli operators, finding $\frac{d x}{d t}$ and $\frac{d z}{d t}$ from the master equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am trying to derive the Bloch vector $dr$ for a measurement of a observable in any arbitrary direction $\theta$. For context this is the setup and derivation I have for continuous measurement along the $z$ axis.

The equation of continuous measurement on observable X has the following form:

$\frac{d \rho}{d t}=\mathcal{D}[X] \rho+\sqrt{\eta} \mathcal{H}[X] \rho \xi(t)$

$\mathcal{D}[X] \rho=X \rho X^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\left(X^{\dagger} X \rho+\rho X^{\dagger} X\right)$

$\mathcal{H}[X] \rho=X \rho+\rho X-\left\langle X+X^{\dagger}\right\rangle \rho$

Kappa is the measurement strength.

In Bloch Vector form,

$\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left(I+x \sigma_{x}+y \sigma_{y}+z \sigma_{z}\right)$

Then,

$\mathcal{D}[X] \rho=2 \kappa\left(\sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{z}-\rho\right)$

$\mathcal{H}[X] \rho=\sqrt{2 \kappa}\left(\sigma_{z} \rho+\rho \sigma_{z}-2 z \rho\right)$

To find $dx$

$\frac{d x}{d t}=\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{x} \rho\right)}{d t}=2 \kappa\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z} \sigma_{x} \sigma_{z} \rho\right)-x\right)+\sqrt{2 \kappa \eta}\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left(\left(\sigma_{x} \sigma_{z}+\sigma_{z} \sigma_{x}\right) \rho\right)-2 x z\right) \xi(t)$

$=-4 \kappa x-\sqrt{8 \kappa \eta} x z \xi(t)$

$\frac{d z}{d t}=\frac{d \operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z} \rho\right)}{d t}=2 \kappa\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z}^{2} \rho \sigma_{z}\right)-\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z} \rho\right)\right)+\sqrt{2 \kappa \eta}\left(\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z}^{2} \rho+\sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{z}\right)-2 z \operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_{z} \rho\right)\right) \xi(t)$

$=\sqrt{8 \kappa \eta}\left(1-z^{2}\right) \xi(t)$

Now I am trying to find the $\frac{d z}{d t}$ and $\frac{d x}{d t}$, in the case that the $\mathcal{D}[X]$ and $\mathcal{H}[X]$ terms for the same master equation where becomes $X = cos(\Theta )\sigma _z+sin(\Theta )\sigma_x$ along measurement angle $\theta$ are:

$\mathcal{D}[X] \rho=X \rho X^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\left(X^{\dagger} X \rho+\rho X^{\dagger} X\right)$

$=\cos ^{2}(\Theta) \sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{z}+\sin ^{2}(\Theta) \sigma_{x} \rho \sigma_{x}+\cos (\Theta) \sin (\Theta) \sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{x}+\cos (\Theta) \sin (\Theta) \sigma_{x} \rho \sigma_{z}$

I am confused on what the simplified form of $\mathcal{H}[X]\rho$ will be as my simplification skills are not very strong

I would also need help in finding $\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{x} \rho\right)}{d t}$ and $\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{z} \rho\right)}{d t}$ with the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms like the above simplification.

Comment: What is $\xi(t)$?  For $t \in \Bbb R$, is $\xi(t)$ a scalar, vector, or matrix?

Comment: Disregard the earlier part of my (now edited) comment; your derivative is fine

Comment: How are we meant to interpret "strength of measurement" here?  Are we meant to plug in $X = (1 - \kappa) I + \kappa \sigma_z$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the $\xi(t)$ term is defined as $\frac{d W(t)}{d t}$ where dW is a Weiner term used in later parts of the calculation for dr. Can you please clarify on what $\frac{d z}{d t}$ and $\frac{d x}{d t}$ will be based on $\mathcal{D}[X] \rho$ and $\mathcal{H}[X] \rho$ of the new form. I am having a bit of trouble finding the derivative using the Trace. Strength of measurement need not be included here.

Comment: The question I really wanted you to answer was "scalar, vector, or operator?".  Based on the way you've been using it, I've assumed that $\xi(t)$ is a scalar.

Comment: I've added what I think the answers should be.  If I find the time, I'll double check my work and write out steps

Comment: Note: my work assumes that the calculations you presented are correct

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I made a mistake with the $\mathcal[D]$ term which I have corrected now which is reflected in my edit. However, I still do not think the $\frac{d x}{d t}$ and \frac{d z}{d t} from your derivation is quite right. I tried taking $\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{x} \rho\right)}{d t}$ and the first term becomes $(\sin ^{2}(\Theta) -\cos ^{2}(\Theta))*x$. Can you please clarify

Comment: sorry for a long delay.  I put together something for $\mathcal D[X]$ now; I can't tell if it matches your work

Comment: Finally went through a full calculation for $\frac{dx}{dt}$, and I can definitively say that my result does not match up at all with yours.

Comment: Note that in simplifying everything, I was using the [cyclic property of trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I am having trouble simplifying $\frac{d z}{d t}$. I am not getting the right form.

Comment: Not sure why you are deleting all the contexts. Now the question is closed because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question: since $\mathcal H[X]$ is a linear with respect to $X$, we have
$$
\mathcal H[\cos(\Theta)\sigma_z + \sin(\Theta)\sigma_x] = 
\cos (\Theta) \mathcal H[\sigma_z] + \sin (\Theta) \mathcal H[\sigma_x].
$$ 
Assuming your computation for $\mathcal H[X] \rho$ is correct, taking $X = \cos(\Theta)\sigma_z + \sin(\Theta)\sigma_x$ should give us
$$
\mathcal H[X]\rho = 
\cos(\Theta)\sqrt{2}\left(\sigma_{z} \rho+\rho \sigma_{z}-2 z \rho\right) + 
\sin(\Theta)\sqrt{2}\left(\sigma_{x} \rho+\rho \sigma_{x}-2 x \rho\right).
$$

---

We should find that
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \left[-4\cos^2 (\Theta)\, x-\sqrt{8 \eta} \cos (\Theta) \,x z\, \xi(t) + \right] + 
 \left[
\sqrt{8 \eta}\sin (\Theta)\left(1-x^{2}\right) \xi(t)
\right]
$$
and 
$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = 
 \left[ \cos \Theta\sqrt{8 \eta}\left(1-z^{2}\right) \xi(t) \right]
+ \left[-4\sin^2 \Theta z-\sqrt{8 \eta}\sin \Theta\, x z \,\xi(t)\right].
$$

---

From scratch:

\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_x \rho) 
= \operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_x \frac{d\rho}{dt}\right) 
= 
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_x 
\mathcal{D}[X] \rho+\sqrt{\eta} \sigma_x\mathcal{H}[X] \rho \xi(t)\right)
\\ & = \operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_x 
\mathcal{D}[X] \rho\right)+ 
\sqrt{\eta}\operatorname{Tr}\left( \sigma_x\mathcal{H}[X] \rho \xi(t)\right)
\end{align}
...
\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}[X] \rho &= X \rho X^{\dagger}-\frac{1}{2}\left(X^{\dagger} X \rho+\rho X^{\dagger} X\right)
\\ & = \cos^2 \Theta \,\sigma_z \rho \sigma_z + \sin^2 \Theta\,\sigma_x \rho \sigma_x + \cos \Theta \sin \Theta [\sigma_z \rho \sigma_x + \sigma_x \rho \sigma_z] - \rho
\end{align}
...
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}\left(\sigma_x 
\mathcal{D}[X] \rho\right) &= 
\operatorname{Tr}\left(
\cos^2 \Theta \,\sigma_x\sigma_z \rho \sigma_z + \sin^2 \Theta\,\sigma_x^2 \rho \sigma_x + \cos \Theta \sin \Theta [\sigma_x\sigma_z \rho \sigma_x + \sigma_x^2 \rho \sigma_z] - \sigma_x\rho
\right)\\
&= \operatorname{Tr}\left(
\cos^2 \Theta \,[\sigma_z\sigma_x\sigma_z] \rho + \sin^2 \Theta\,\rho \sigma_x + \cos \Theta \sin \Theta [\sigma_x^2\sigma_z \rho + \sigma_z\sigma_x^2 \rho] - \sigma_x\rho
\right)
\\ &=
\operatorname{Tr}\left(
-\cos^2 \Theta \,\sigma_x \rho + \sin^2 \Theta\,\rho \sigma_x + \cos \Theta \sin \Theta [\sigma_z \rho + \sigma_z \rho] - \sigma_x\rho
\right)
\\ &=
(\sin^2\Theta - \cos^2\Theta - 1)\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_x \rho) + 2 \cos \Theta \sin \Theta\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_z \rho)
\\ & = 
(\sin^2\Theta - \cos^2\Theta - 1)x + 2 \cos \Theta \sin \Theta z
\end{align}
... Noting that $X = X^\dagger$,
\begin{align}
\mathcal H[X] \rho &= 
X \rho+\rho X-\left\langle X+X^{\dagger}\right\rangle \rho = 
X \rho+\rho X- 2\left\langle X\right\rangle \rho
\\ & = 
\cos \Theta[\sigma_z \rho + \rho\sigma_z] + \sin \Theta[\sigma_x \rho + \rho \sigma_x] - 2(\cos \Theta \,z + \sin \Theta \,x) \rho 
\end{align}
....
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_x \mathcal H[X] \rho) &= 
\operatorname{Tr}(
\cos \Theta[\sigma_x\sigma_z \rho + \sigma_x\rho\sigma_z] + \sin \Theta[\sigma_x^2 \rho + \sigma_x\rho \sigma_x] - 2(\cos \Theta \,z + \sin \Theta \,x) \rho 
)
\\ & = 
\operatorname{Tr}(
\cos \Theta[(\sigma_x\sigma_z + \sigma_z \sigma_x)\rho] + \sin \Theta[\rho + \sigma_x^2\rho] - 2(\cos \Theta \,z + \sin \Theta \,x) \rho 
)
\\ & = 
\operatorname{Tr}(
\cos \Theta[0\cdot\rho] + \sin \Theta[2\rho] - 2(\cos \Theta \,z + \sin \Theta \,x) \rho 
)
\\ & = 
2(\sin \Theta - \cos \Theta \,z - \sin \Theta x)\operatorname{Tr}(\rho) = 
2(\sin \Theta - \cos \Theta \,z - \sin \Theta x).
\end{align}
....
\begin{align}
\frac{d x}{dt} &= 
(\sin^2\Theta - \cos^2\Theta - 1)x + 2 \cos \Theta \sin \Theta z + 
2\sqrt{\eta}\xi(t)(\sin \Theta - \cos \Theta \,z - \sin \Theta x)
\\ & = 
2 \sqrt{\eta}\xi(t) \sin \Theta + 
(\sin^2\Theta - \cos^2\Theta - 1 - 2 \sqrt{\eta}\xi(t) \sin \Theta)x
+ 2(\cos \Theta \sin \Theta - \sqrt{\eta}\xi(t) \cos \Theta)z
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain how the $\cos^2(\theta)$ and $\sin^2(theta)$ from finding the $\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{x} \rho\right)}{d t}$ and $\frac{d T r\left(\sigma_{z} \rho\right)}{d t}$ when differentiating $D[X] \rho$ disappears please? I assumed that when $\mathcal{D}[X] \rho= \cos ^{2}(\Theta) \sigma_{z} \rho \sigma_{z}+\sin ^{2}(\Theta) \sigma_{x} \rho \sigma_{x}$ is plugged into the Trace and while taking its derivative is there not a $\cos^2(\theta)$ term that appears in the final form. Please clarify

Comment: @Ian It disappeared because I made a silly mistake; sorry about that. I'll see if I can fix my work here

Comment: @Ian see my latest edit. Still, I'll try and do these calculations from scratch when I have the chance to really look

Comment: I am still having trouble simplifying $\frac{d z}{d t}$